# Multithreaded file transfer via socket in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, file-transfer

I want to receive chunks of a file from multi-thread and write in orderly.

I have a server file on one system that send a file into 4 chunks through 4 thread now i have a client program on another machine i want to receive that files with 4 threads and write that to disk in correct order. I have no idea to receive and write in order can you help?!

Thanks for advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except possibly in an extraordinary case, there is absolutely no reason to do this. A single thread can retrieve data from a Socket far faster than the data is transmitted.

But if you did want to do this, you could do something like

```
public static class Multireceiver implements Runnable {
  static AtomicInteger step = new AtomicInteger(0);
  InputStream s;
  int spot;
  public Multireceiver (InputStream in) {
    s = in;
  }
  public void run() {
    spot = step.incrementAndGet();
    //grab a bunch of bytes and put them in an object with the step number attached
  }

}
```

Then you just need to order your partial downloads by spot and reassemble the data. But again, all of this is normally unnecessary

Comment: One way that using 4 threads will be faster than using 1 thread is if there are 2 other processes on the same PC that are downloading very large files at the same time. Then having 4 threads might give this process 4/6 of the available resources, instead of 1/3.

Comment: @k314159 re: 4/6 of the available resources - In all likelihood, only one of those 4 threads is going to be "awake" at a time. The rest will likely be stuck waiting for more bytes to come in. So again, I think except in extreme cases multithreading won't help.

Comment: True. In the case of sending, however, let's say two other processes are each sending a large file. Then if this process uses 4 threads, the OS may see a total of 6 threads each waiting to use a single resource (network interface) and may assign equal time to each thread.